# Pagination iteration counter

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

If I have a view with a foreach loop and an iteration counter, how would I continue that counter on another page when using pagination?

My view's loop:

```
<?php $i = 0; ?>
@foreach ($countries as $country)
    {{ $i }}
    <?php $i++; ?>
@endforeach
```

The route:

```
$countries = Country::paginate(10);
return View::make('index')->with('countries', $countries);
```

As I have it set up now, if I go to the second page of the pagination, it will start the counter at 1 again, rather than at 10, then 20, and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
<?php $i = 1; $skipped = $countries->currentPage() * $countries->perPage(); ?>

@foreach ($countries as $country)
    {{ $skipped + $i }}
    <?php $i++; ?>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Modified to `<?php $i = 1 + $countries->getCurrentPage() * $countries->getPerPage() - $countries->getPerPage(); ?>` and kept `{{ $i }}`. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

For laravel 5.6 this should work directly from your blade:

`{{ $loop->iteration + $countries->firstItem() - 1 }}`

Answer (score 1):

Modified to a global answer:

```
$item = $item->paginate(10);
$skipped = ($item->currentPage() * $item->perPage()) - $item->perPage();
```

Then in your blade file:

```
{{ $loop->iteration + $skipped }}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 @foreach($models as $key => $model)
    {{ $models->firstItem()+$key }}
 @endforeach
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.